# Lighting DOM XSS attack reported by chekmarx

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We have received checkmarx report from client where there are 10-12 issues are related to lightning DOM XSS attack.
In majority cases, issues are related to attributes are assigned using the apex callout and being embedded in HTML tags.
e.g.

```
<!-- AURA Component -->
<aura:attribute name="helpLinks" type="Object"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.helpLinks.disclaimerLinkCSList}" var="helpLink">
<a class="footerLinks" href="{!helpLink.link__c}">
    {!helpLink.Name}
</a>
```

HELPER

```
 
   helper.callServer(
    component, 
    "c.getHelpLink", 
    function(response){
        if(!$A.util.isEmpty(response)){                    
            component.set("v.helpLinks", response);
        }
    }
    
);
```

I have done some research and want to clarify below:

- Is it not a false positive as binding attribute is not a user input but got assigned from APEX callout?
- if not, how attacker will be able to manipulate the script
- I understand that best practice is always use the AURA components. Does it mean we can never use HTML tags with aura:attributes

Checkmarx:
The application's implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" embeds untrusted data in the generated output with link__c, at line 1 of forceapp/main/default/aura/xyz/xyz.cmp. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it not a false positive as binding attribute is not a user input but got assigned from APEX callout?

Checkmarx can't know where the data is coming from. Since it's a field value, it could be coming from, for example, a web-to-lead record that has malicious links in it. I wouldn't necessarily classify it as a "false positive," it's just that it's heuristically impossible to prove it is a "true negative."

> if not, how attacker will be able to manipulate the script

If a user gains access to the appropriate records, they can inject any link they want in there. That's how it is theoretically calculated. Note that this may or may not be an actual problem (see above). That said, many admins get their security configuration wrong, and this could allow for an unforeseen exploit.

> I understand that best practice is always use the AURA components. Does it mean we can never use HTML tags with aura:attributes

There's no inherent danger as far as injection is concerned. Aura will appropriate encode the properties, such that it is impossible to inject extra attributes or run JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, your answers make sense. I want to clarify few things given below
1. Why I think it is false positive? Yes, it is correct that checmarx don't know how data was saved in the field. In our case, it is a custom setting record being updated by System admin only. 
Considering this, is it safe to not fix this? 
Apart from using lightning:navigation  , is there any better/quick way to fix this  ?

Comment: @AbhishekDEV As long as it's documented, I don't see a reason to fix it, just be aware that it may be a risk.